# How to display the column names of tables without dots replacing spaces and removing the table name in Shiny App?

Tags: r, function, shiny

I am building a complex Shiny App with many tables that are produced as the output of a function that I call here test for simplicity.

I then want to display theses tables with the right column names that i have assigned through the function, however they show  with dots instead of spaces or parenthesis. On top of that, the name of the table is also displayed (which I don't want)

Any idea on how to display the correct column names: var test 1 and var test (2)?

Below, my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot)


ui <- fluidPage(


  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("A","Test",choices=c(1,2,3)),
      actionButton("go","GO")
    ),


    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("graph1"),
      tableOutput("table1")
    )

  ))

server <- function(input, output) {

  test<-function(A){
    C<-(1:3)
    A<-as.numeric(A)
    dfA<-data.frame(A,C)
    colnames(dfA)<-c("var test 1","var test (2)")
    g1<-dfA


    g2<-ggplot(data = dfA, aes(x=`var test 1`, y=`var test (2)`))+
      geom_point(shape=1)


    outputs<-list("output1"=g1,
                  "output2"=g2)
  }


  model_output<-eventReactive(input$go,{
    test(input$A)
  })

  output$graph1<-renderPlot({
    model_output()[2]

  })
  output$table1<-renderTable({
    model_output()[1]

  })



}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is in the extraction of `list` elements.  It should be `[[` instead of `[` because when we do `[`, it is still a `list` with one element

```
model_output()[[1]]
```

and

```
model_output()[[2]]
```

If we try to reproduce the issue

```
o1 <- list(g1 = data.frame(`var test 1` = 1, `var test (2)` = 1:3, check.names = FALSE))
o1[1]
$g1 # note it is still a `list`
#  var test 1 var test (2)
#1          1            1
#2          1            2
#3          1            3

str(o1[1])
List of 1
# $ g1:'data.frame':    3 obs. of  2 variables:
# ..$ var test 1  : num [1:3] 1 1 1
#  ..$ var test (2): int [1:3] 1 2 3

o1[[1]]
#   var test 1 var test (2)
#1          1            1
#2          1            2
#3          1            3
```

-full code

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)


ui <- fluidPage(


  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("A","Test",choices=c(1,2,3)),
      actionButton("go","GO")
    ),


    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("graph1"),
      tableOutput("table1")
    )

  ))

server <- function(input, output) {

  test<-function(A){
    C<-(1:3)
    A<-as.numeric(A)
    dfA<-data.frame(A,C)
    colnames(dfA)<-c("var test 1","var test (2)")
    g1<-dfA


    g2<-ggplot(data = dfA, aes(x=`var test 1`, y=`var test (2)`))+
      geom_point(shape=1)


    outputs<-list("output1"=g1,
                  "output2"=g2)
  }


  model_output<-eventReactive(input$go,{
    test(input$A)
  })

  output$graph1<-renderPlot({
    model_output()[[2]]

  })
  output$table1<-renderTable({
    model_output()[[1]]

  })



}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: I agree, it works great now, the answer is super useful! Many thanks!